# Running extendscript (.jsx) launches ExtendscriptToolkit

Tags: photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I have written a couple of simple .JSX scripts that automate some common monkeywork I do in Photoshop.

I wrote the scripts in ExtendScriptToolkit and then execute them with `File > Scripts > Browse` and select the script I want. This runs the script and does what I want it to but it also launches ExtendScriptToolkit again each time. I have passed the script to a few others at work and they have all asked me to fix this so that the script executes purely within Photoshop but I can't make it work.

Basically, how can I run the script from Photoshop without it launching the script editor as well?

Cheers in advance for your help

Comment: do you use the `$.writeln("Something");` statement? This launches ESTK. Also which PS version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your script for `$.writeln()` statements. This could be a problem. You can also suppress debugging by setting the debug level.

Taken from the Object Model Viewer in ESTK

```
// $.level   
// Data Type: number 
// Core JavaScript Classes 
// The current debugging level, which enables or disables the JavaScript debugger.
// One of 0 (no debugging), 1 (break on runtime errors), or 2 (full debug mode).

$.level = 0; 
$.writeln("something");
alert("Hello World");
```

**Edit:**
I tried the debug level with the script above. It still opens the ESTK :-(
Looks like it does not work. Can anybody confirm this?

Comment: Level doesn't work for me on Win7 CS3 or CS5.  writeln always brings up the ESTK.  I always make sure to remove all writeln statement before I publish a script to production...

Comment: I'd removed all the writln statements from my main script but left one in one of the little util scripts that just wrote a blank line so I completely missed it. Removed this and it is working now cheers.

Comment: I always add a global variable called DEBUG and than add `if(DEBUG) $.writeln()` works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

> $.level = 0;

"The current debugging level, which enables or disables the JavaScript
debugger. **Read only.**" Page 217

But when script run from ESTK $.level == 1

When from APP $.level == 0

Аnd solution may be `if ($.level) $.writeln("JSC");`